# BackgroundWorker wpf c#

Tags: wpf

```
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.DoWork += (m, s) =>
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Bilgi());  //1-
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => Amortisman();  //2-
            };
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Bilgi(); = is an animation,

Amortisman() = is a calculation, it checks the textboxes and prints the calculated values ​​in the textboxes.

What I want to do is Amortisman() I should place it somewhere so that While the Bilgi() animation is shown, Amortisman() is also executed, makes the calculation and prints it to the textboxes. The animation works fine.
I browsed hundreds of pages, but I didn't find a suitable BackgroundWorker for myself.
I couldn't find it, everyone uses a progressbar, what I want to do is to run the animation.
please help

I am sorry for my English

Comment: Some considerations: the BackgroundWorker is completely redundant in your rendered scenario. You are creating a background tread only to post the work back to the UI thread (`Dispatcher.Invoke`). You also replace the `BackgroundWorker` with the `Task` library. If you use data binding, you don't have to directly access the TextBoxes or other UI elements in general. This also eliminates the need for the `Dispatcher`.

Comment: Your current code is not behaving as expected because the animation is preventing the Amortisman() from execution. Because you have dispatched the operation to the UI thread Amortisman() must wait until the Dispatcher is free, which will be after the Bilgi() method has completed.

Answer (score 0):

You must execute the calculations in parallel, concurrently with the animation. The `Bilgi` method is currently blocking `Amortisman` because it is executed on the same thread (UI thread) as Bilgi.

```cs
private void Run()
{
  // Make sure this line is called on the UI thread!
  IProgress<string> progressReporter = new Progress<string>(UpdateTextBox); 

  // Execute the calculations on a background thread and continue
  Task.Run(() => Amortisman(progressReporter));

  // Start the animation on the UI thread 
  // while the calculations are running in the background
  Bilgi(); 
}

private void Amortisman(IProgress<string> progressReporter)
{
  // TODO::Perform calculations

  // Write to the TextBox
  string textValue = "Some text to display from the background thread";
  progressReporter.Report(textValue);
}

// The callback for the Progress<T> instance
private void UpdateTextBox(string textValue)
{
  this.TextBox.Text = textValue;
}
```

Comment: Depreciation and information are working properly. What is important for me is that depreciation should do its job while executing the information, or when depreciation runs for the first time, it freezes and crashes. It works fine for 2.3 times. What is important for me is that it works for the first time.

Comment: Please do not edit the post in order to communicate. Use comments please. Are you saying that the posted example is not working because it crashes the application?

Comment: No, I couldn't manage to integrate the code you sent, my application freezes when the depreciation first runs.

Comment: Then this is not related to the pattern I showed you. Do you get any exception? In yor question you wrote that `Amortisman` is referencing TextBox element in order to read their values? if this is the case you must read all required value *before* you start the background thread. read the values and pass them to the `Amortisman` method as arguments. You can create a parameter object if the number of parameters would be too big (> 3). The goal is to prevent `Amortisman` from depending on UI elements.

Comment: Step 1) Collect input data for `Amortisman`. Step 2) Run `Amortisman` like shown in this example with the collected input data.

Comment: I think I will rewrite the depreciation, the code is too long, I tried it now and it gives an expectation error in my own running code.

Comment: I think this is not related to your original question. Even if your code won't throw exceptions the way you run background threads is wrong. This answer solves this problem and shows a clean solution. You should integrate it after you have fixed your code.

Comment: Ok last question please your answer will be appreciated if you know

Comment: public class Ticker : INotifyPropertyChanged
     {
         public Ticker()
         {
             Timer timer = new Timer();
             timer.Interval = 1000;
             timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
             timer.Start();
         }
         public DateTime Now
         {
             get { return DateTime.Now; }
         }
         void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
         {
             PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Now"));
         }
         public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

Comment: This code works fine but not for me because it takes the system time, I think it should be obtained from the internet. Does anyone know the way to do this?

Comment: What time do you want?

Comment: If you want "the internet" to be the time source then you need to find a time server and check out the REST API documentation to understand how the request must be formed and how the response is decoded.. Then send a HTTP request to get the current time stamp. However, every modern OS uses a time server to synchronize its system clock. You won't get more precision from a manual time server query. I think you should use the system time. Next, instead of raising the PropertyChanged event every second, assign the new value to the `Now` property and raise the event from the property setter.

Comment: Also polling every second is too slow as this will create a glitch. You must use at least half the frequency of the signal you want to sample. So 0.5s would be a better timer frequency.